# preg_replace_all() related issue

Tags: php, function, replace, bbcode

I am currently making a BBCode class for my website.
I need to do the following.

```
function bbCode([skill]Q[/skill]_________[skill]Q[/skill]_________[skill]Q[/skill]);
```

bbCode function has to replace all Q's between [skill] and [/skill] tags, and replace it with $skillArray['Q'] value.  ($skillArray is character dependant.)

How can I do this?

A little clearer version is:

1. For example you're on a page of "Orc" character.
2. [skill]Q[/skill] tag should get "Orc's Q skill name" automatically.
3. For example you're on a page of "Hunter" character.
4. [skill]Q[/skill] tag should get "Hunter's Q skill name" automatically.

Ps. Don't want to use explode.

Comment: Do you want to replace all Q's or just anything between `[skill]` and `[/skill]` ?

Comment: Q's should be between [skill] and [/skill].

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the tags you want to be replaced are within some form of template, you could use file_get_contents and then loop through the tags you want to replace with the desired values, for example:

```
$file = file_get_contents ( 'yourfile.php' );

$skillArray = array ( 'Q' => 'Hunter name' );

foreach ( $skillArray as $key => $val )
{
    $file = str_replace ( '[skill]' . $key . '[\skill]', $val, $file );
}
```

Thats just a completely rough example, but if I'm understanding what you are trying to do; that should be along the right lines....

Comment: This will loop only once due to only one value in array. There can be 15x [skill] Q [/skill] BBCode in a comment. It will only replace the first then.<br><br>I want it to replace all of them in once.

Comment: Yeah thats fine, this was just an example of how you could implement it. You could put as many items in the array as you wanted, and it would loop for that time...

Comment: It should work I agree, but I was expecting it to do with different function like preg_replace_all(). Doing it with str_replace in a for loop isn't the thing I wanted. :)

Comment: @AnılÜnal he just gave the idea. You need to do it yourself.

Comment: @Shiplu Yeah, I know, but there is no array. There is only a string. I can't really do anything with his suggestion. :)

Comment: You will need an array of some kind to determine what to 'skill' to replace with what value...

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```
$data = "[skill]Q[/skill]_________[skill]Q[/skill]_________[skill]Q[/skill]";
$r['Q'] = "Yahoo";
function b($a){
    global $r;
    return $r[$a[1]];
}
$data = preg_replace_callback('|\[skill\](Q)\[\/skill\]|', 'b' , $data);
var_dump($data);
```

If you want to replace all the `Q`s with single "Yahoo" use `Q+` instead of `Q`. If you want to match all words use `\w+`.

Comment: Could you explain the B function? Didn't see a function being called like this before. <br><br>Does preg_replace_callback automatically calls the function of second string parameter?

Comment: This is a call back function that is called with *matches* as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$skillArray=array('Q'=>'fishing');
$txt="test [skill]Q[/skill]  test";
$txt=preg_replace("#\[skill\](.*)\[\/skill\]#e",'$skillArray["$1"]',$txt);
echo $txt; //test fishing test
?>
```